# For which values of $x$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ x^n}{x^{2n} -1}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Of course it does not converge for $x = \pm 1$. I tried to use the limit form of the comparison test, using a divisor "b" series of $x^n$, and $\frac{1}{x^{2n} -1}$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ for $|x| > 1$, BUT my test series converges only for $|x| < 1$ so I am likely using this incorrectly. for $|x| < 1$ I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $\;x^{2n}-1=(x^n-1)(x^n+1)\;$ , so in fact

$$\frac{x^n}{x^{2n}-1}=\frac{x^n}{\left(x^n-1\right)\left(x^n+1\right)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{x^n-1}+\frac1{x^n+1}\right)$$

Try now to attack it from here.

*Added by request*: for $\;|x|<1\;$ we have the limit comparison theorem with $\;\cfrac1{|x|^n}\;$ :

$$\frac{\cfrac1{|x^n\pm1|}}{\cfrac1{|x^n|}}=\frac{|x|^n}{|x^n\pm1|}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and since the geometric series $\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\cfrac1{x^n}\;$ converges *absolutely* for $\;|x|<1\;$, so do both our series.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{x^n\pm1}$$

Observe we used above the strong one-direction limit comparison test for non-negative series:

$$\text{If}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0\;\;\text{ and}\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\;\;\text{converges, then so does}\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$

Comment: I don't think I appreciated the foundation you need in algebra and trig, for calculus, calculating limits, convergence. There is often some algebraic manipulation. In the above case, I think I can use the series 1/x^n as the convergent test series in the limit comparison test to show  convergence for abs x > 1. (I inadvertently indicated x^n in the initial problem)  where I am in the math book I have not gotten to the ratio and other tests yet, so can't use that. only integral test, limit compare, and compare, and Cauchy. sorry I did not mention.

Comment: I am still struggling in the case abs x < 1. Could you follow thru with your construction above to show what this series does in that interval? again I have only limited tests I should be using, noted in prev comment to show what happens. ans in my book says it converges for abs x < 1. thanks.

Comment: @ChuckS. Please read what I added to my answer.

Comment: oh good grief. I WAS looking at the limit compare theorem and it stipulates series a and series b being series of positive terms and I am looking at series 1/(x^n -1) for 0<x<1, for example, and I think, hmm, I can't use the limit compare because this is a negative term series. why did I not realize that I can look at series: abs a and abs b, prove convergence which then indicates, by theorem, that the series, a and series b converge, and therefore series a + b converge. I was messing around trying to sum these series. thanks for the patience. best ans for ME, at my level.

Comment: I hate to bring this up, and maybe I still don't get it, but while writing up the soln above for my notes, I think that the series 1 to inf 1/x^n converges for abs x > 1 (1/x). I think the technique shown works for abs x > 1. And the limit compare of the ratio goes to 1 as n goes to inf.

Comment: @ChuckS. Nop. I hardly remembered this question, but a geometric series converges iff its ratio in absolute value is less than one, so $\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{x^n}\;$ converges iff $\;|x|<1\;$ . I'm not sure what you meant with that  x> 1(1/x),  but the above covers what you need.

Comment: what I meant is that if |x| < 1, then 1/|x| > 1. the ratio is > 1. sum 0 to inf  x^n would converge if |x| < 1.

Answer (score 5):

If we set $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{x^{2n}-1}$ we have that $f_n(x)=- f_n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, so it is enough to prove convergence over $x\in(-1,1)$ to have convergence over $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,+1\}$. But if $|x|<1$ we have:
$$ \frac{x^n}{1-x^{2n}} = x^{n}+x^{3n}+x^{5n}+\ldots $$
so:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{1-x^{2n}} = \sum_{n\geq 1} \bar{\sigma}(n)\,x^n $$
where $\bar{\sigma}(n)$ is the number of odd divisors of $n$. But obviously $1\leq\bar{\sigma}(n)\leq n$, hence the radius of convergence of the previous power series is one and we are done.

Comment: thanks. I am still studying this a bit. a bit beyond my experience to imagine this solution, but I think I basically see the last equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** For $\lvert x\rvert<1$, use ratio test and see what you get.

**Hint 2:** For $\lvert x\rvert>1$, use ratio test and see what you get.